# Probability of going to school A

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I commute to teach at one of two schools everyday by train.
I live at the terminal station where every 30 min there is a train leaving for school A, every 60  min there is a train leaving for school B. I will jump on the earliest train available at the station and teach at that school.

My  question is: What is the probability I teach at school A?   Since the frequency of the train leaving for school A is twice compared to that of the train leave for school B, my guess is that the probability is $\frac{2}{3}$. However, I am not sure if my intuition is correct. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't think there's enough info to give an answer. Let's say the B train leaves on the hour, and the A train leaves at $x$ and $x+30$ minutes past the hour. Then the probability of taking the A train is $(x+30)/60$.

Comment: To model this, you need to make some assumptions. Are the arrival times random? Are the arrival times of the two trains independent Poisson point processes? If they are, and the times until each of the trains arrive after you decide you’re ready are independent random variables that each have an exponential distribution, the you would integrate the joint PDF in the appropriate region to find the probability that train 1 arrives before train 2.

Comment: Yes, my arrival time is random and I do not know the buses' schedule.  The only thing I know is the departure  frequencies of the two trains, and their departures are independent to each other. I believe there should be some simple solutions to this question.

Comment: But when you write “every 30 min there is a train leaving for school A”, does that mean that there is deterministically 30 minutes between arrivals? Or is the inter arrival time random? If so, do you know the distribution of inter arrival times, or only the expected value? Different distributions would give different answers. Usually these types of problems are modeled as Poisson processes, with inter arrival times that are exponentially distributed.

Comment: It is deterministically 30 mins beteeen arrivals. We know for sure to see train  A leaving within 30 min and  train B leaving within 60 mins after my arrival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is a sort of puzzle, which makes all sorts of (mostly unwarranted) simplifying assumptions. So I assume

$\bullet$ Train *A* arrives/departs punctually and instantaneously at $8:00, 8:30, 9:00,..$

$\bullet$ Train *B* arrives/ departs punctually and instantaneously at $8:15$, $9:15$, etc.

$\bullet$ I arrive with equal probability at any time  between $8:00$ and $9:00$ and catch whichever train arrives next.

So if  I arrive between $8:00$ and $8:15$, I catch train $B$ and if I arrive between $8:15$ and $8:30$, it is train $A$
If I arrive between $8:30$ and $9:00$ I will only get train $A$, so  overall probability of catching train $A$ and hence going to school $A = \frac12\frac12 + 1\cdot\frac12 = \frac34$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! From the moment I step in the station, one thing is sure: I will see train A within 30 min, and train B within 60 min,  I do see them differently, the probability does not seem to be the  same.

Comment: Oh, I considered only the first half of the cycle. Corrected.

Comment: This makes sense now :-)

Comment: I like your approach for this problem, since it is applicable  to the cases of 3 ($\frac{2}{3} probability$) or more  trains. However, to manually calculate for them, it seems a very tedious work (of course, this is just for fun). I asked an extended question to seek if there is a formula can be derived.