# Probability of going to school $A_1$ when there are 9 more other possibilities

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I am  curious to an extension of the previous question [Probability of going to school A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072709/probability-of-going-to-school-a)
and  want to extend the schools from 3 to 10.

Now the story begins : I commute to teach at one of $A_i$ (i from 1 to 10) schools everyday by train. I live at the terminal station where every 5 x i mins (i.e.,5,10,15,20,... mins)there is a train leaving for school $Ai_i$ punctually, but the actual departure times are unknown to me.  I will jump on the earliest train available at the station and teach at that school(if they arrive the same time, I have equal probability for each one of them).

My question is: What is the probability I teach at school A$_1$? I can manually do it  for cases of  2,3,4 schools following the procedure provided from the answer. Is there a formula I can use to directly calculate when the school options grow to 10?

**EDIT:**

> Actually, when there are only 2 schools $A_1$ and $A_2$ to choose
> from, there is a 2D geometry solution (as shown below):
>
> Points within the 5 min by 10 min rectangle represent all possible
> next departure  times of $A_1$ and $A_2$.For example P(1.5,3) means
> next $A_1$ departs at 1.5 min later, and $A_2$ departs at 3 min later.
>
> Any points above  the 45$^\circ$ line represent cases when $A_1$
> departs earlier than $A_2$ (when points are on this 45$\circ$ line,
> the probabilities for me to take each is both 50%.
>
> So the probability to go to school  $A_1$ is the (1- $\frac{S_\triangle}{S\square}$)= 75%.
>
> But, I find it hard to extend to 3D,4D,...

[image]

Comment: You should be clearer about the train timetable since presumably trains do not leave at the same time.  Your chart does not help: I would have thought you are more likely to go to school $A_1$ since it has more frequent trains.

Comment: I agree with @above. For example, what happens if trains going to school $A_1$ and $A_3$ both arrive at $9:00$. Then which school would you go to? Are you guaranteeing that no two trains come at the same time? Do we assume that the time at which you arrive at the train station is random?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment. Updated my question in EDIT section to explain how 75% probability is obtained for A1 (corrected a typo too, should be 1- ratio, not ratio itself)). Also clarified when trains depart at the same time, you have the same probability to jump on each one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,\dots,X_{n}$ be independent random variables with $X_i$ distributed uniformly in $[0,i]$. You're asking for $P(\min_iX_i=X_1)$. It's fairly clear that this is
$$
\left.
\int_0^1\int_{x_1}^2\int_{x_1}^3\dots\int_{x_1}^n dx_n\dots dx_2dx_1
\middle/
\int_0^1\int_0^2\int_0^3\dots\int_0^n dx_n\dots dx_2dx_1
\right.
\\=\frac1{n!}\int_0^1\prod_{i=2}^n(i-x_1) dx_1.
$$

The integrand is a polynomial in $x_1$, so for a given value of $n$, you can expand it (using e.g. [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)) in order to evaluate the integral. Maybe someone else will find a simpler closed-form answer.

Comment: Thanks for such a great solution!